# Unresolved external symbol __aullshr when optimization is turned off

Tags: c, visual-c++, intrinsics, bit-fields, uefi

I am compiling a piece of UEFI C code with Visual Studio 2015 C/C++ compiler.

The compiler is targeting **IA32**, not X64.

When turning on the optimization with "/O1", the build is OK.

When **turning off** the optimization with "/Od", the build gives below error:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __aullshr
```

According to [here](https://uefi.blogspot.com/2010/02/why-why-do-i-get-unresolved-externals.html), there's an explanation why *this kind of* functions can be called implicitly by the compiler:

> It turns out that this function is one of several **compiler support
>   functions** that are invoked explicitly by the Microsoft C/C++ compiler.
>   In this case, this function is called whenever the 32-bit compiler
>   needs to multiply two 64-bit integers together. The EDK does not link
>   with Microsoft's libraries and does not provide this function.
>
> Are there other functions like this one? Sure, several more for 64-bit
>   division, remainder and **shifting**.

But according to [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function):

> ...Compilers that implement **intrinsic functions** generally enable them
>   **only when a program requests optimization**...

So how could such functions still be called when I explicitly turned off the optimization with `/Od`??

### ADD 1 - 2:32 PM 2/16/2019

It seems I am wrong about the `__aullshr` function.

**It is not a compiler intrinsic function.** According to [here](https://hero.handmade.network/forums/code-discussion/t/94-guide_-_how_to_avoid_c_c++_runtime_on_windows), it turns out to be a runtime library function, whose implementation can be found in: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\crt\src\intel\ullshr.asm` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\crt\src\i386\ullshr.asm`

Such VC runtime functions are brought in by the compiler for 32-bit applications to do 64-bit operations.

But I still don't know why `/O1` can build pass while `/Od` failed? 
It seems optimization switch can affect the usage of VC runtime library.

### ADD 2 - 4:59 PM 2/17/2019

I found the code that cause the build failure.

It turns out to be some **C struct bit field operation**. There's a 64-bit C struct which has a lot of bit fields backed by a single UINT64 variable. When I comment out the single line of code that access these bit fields, the build is pass. It seems `_aullshr()` function is used to access these bit fields when `/Od` is specified.

Since this is part of the firmware code, I am wondering if it is a good practice to turn-off the optimization with `/Od`?

### ADD 3 - 9:33 AM 2/18/2019

I created below minimal reproducible example for VS2015.

First, there's a static lib project:

**(test.c)**

```
typedef unsigned __int64    UINT64;

typedef union {
    struct {
        UINT64 field1 : 16;
        UINT64 field2 : 16;
        UINT64 field3 : 6;
        UINT64 field4 : 15;
        UINT64 field5 : 2;
        UINT64 field6 : 1;
        UINT64 field7 : 1;
        UINT64 field8 : 1;  //<=========
        UINT64 field9 : 1;
        UINT64 field10 : 1;
        UINT64 field11 : 1;
        UINT64 field12 : 1; //<=========
        UINT64 field13 : 1;
        UINT64 field14 : 1;
    } Bits;
    UINT64 Data;
} ISSUE_STRUCT;


int
Method1
(
    UINT64        Data
)
{
    ISSUE_STRUCT              IssueStruct;
    IssueStruct.Data = Data;

    if (IssueStruct.Bits.field8 == 1 && IssueStruct.Bits.field12 == 1) { // <==== HERE
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Then a Windows DLL project:

**(DllMain.c)**

```
#include <Windows.h>
typedef unsigned __int64    UINT64;

int
Method1
(
    UINT64        Data
);

int __stdcall DllMethod1
(
    HINSTANCE hinstDLL,
    DWORD fdwReason,
    LPVOID lpReserved
)
{
    if (Method1(1234)) //<===== Use the Method1 from the test.obj
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 2;
}
```

Build process:

First, compile the **test.obj**:

> cl.exe /nologo **/arch:IA32** /c /GS- /W4 /Gs32768 /D UNICODE **/O1b2** /GL
>   /EHs-c- /GR- /GF /Gy /Zi /Gm /Gw **/Od** /Zl **test.c**

(**add**: VC++ 2015 compiler gives below warning for `test.obj`:

> warning C4214: nonstandard extension used: bit field types other than
>   int

)

Then compile the **DllMain.obj**:

> cl /nologo **/arch:IA32** /c /GS- /W4 /Gs32768 /D UNICODE **/O1b2** /GL
>   /EHs-c- /GR- /GF /Gy /Zi /Gm /Gw **/Od** /Zl DllMain.c

Then link the **DllMain.obj** to the **test.obj**

> link DllMain.obj ..\aullshr\test.obj /NOLOGO /NODEFAULTLIB
>   /IGNORE:4001 /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF=10 /MAP /ALIGN:32 /SECTION:.xdata,D
>   /SECTION:.pdata,D **/MACHINE:X86** /LTCG /SAFESEH:NO /DLL
>   /ENTRY:DllMethod1 /DRIVER

It will give below error:

> Generating code Finished generating code test.obj : error LNK2001:
>   **unresolved external symbol __aullshr** DllMain.dll : fatal error
>   LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

1. If I remove the bit field manipulation code at **HERE** in the test.c, the link error will disappear.
2. If I only remove the **/Od** from the compile options for the **test.c**, the link error will disappear.

### ADD 4 - 12:40 PM 2/18/2019

Thanks to @PeterCordes in his comment, there's an even simpler way to reproduce this issue. Just invoke below method:

```
uint64_t shr(uint64_t a, unsigned c) { return a >> c; }
```

Then compile the source code with below command:

> **cl** /nologo /arch:IA32 /c /GS- /W4 /Gs32768 /D UNICODE /O1b2 /GL
>   /EHs-c- /GR- /GF /Gy /Zi /Gm /Gw /Od /Zl DllMain.c
>
> **link** DllMain.obj /NOLOGO /NODEFAULTLIB /IGNORE:4001 /OPT:REF
>   /OPT:ICF=10 /MAP /ALIGN:32 /SECTION:.xdata,D /SECTION:.pdata,D
>   /MACHINE:X86 /LTCG /SAFESEH:NO /DLL /ENTRY:DllMethod1 /DRIVER

This issue can be reproduced for:

- Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.40629 for x86  (VS2013)
- Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24210 for x86  (VS2015)
- Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24215.1 for x86 (VS2015)

As mandated in the [UEFI coding standard 5.6.3.4 Bit Fields](https://edk2-docs.gitbooks.io/edk-ii-c-coding-standards-specification/content/5_source_files/56_declarations_and_types.html#table-8-efi-constants) :

> Bit fields may only be of type INT32, signed INT32, UINT32, or a
>   typedef name defined as one of the three INT32 variants.

So my final solution is to modify the UEFI code to use `UINT32` instead of `UINT64`.

Comment: Not much of a mystery, /O1 removes unnecessary code.  Google "visual c++ how to generate an assembly listing" to get ahead.

Comment: Or maybe with optimization the compiler realizes that `a * (uint64_t)b` is actually a 32x32 => 64-bit multiply and uses 1-operand `mul r32` to produce a 64-bit result in EDX:EAX.  But with optimization disabled, it probably actually zero-extends both inputs and calls a 64x64 => 64-bit multiply function.  https://godbolt.org/z/si5064 Nope, nevermind, MSVC isn't that bad even in `-Od`  mode.

Comment: You have what seems to be a compiler bug: can you post the structure definition and offending code in a minimal program that exhibits the problem when compiled with `/Od` ?

Comment: @chqrlie Let me check if this is proprietary code and post it later.

Comment: @chqrlie I added a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your build setup for creating UEFI applications omits the static library of helper functions that MSVC's code-gen expects to be available.  MSVC's code-gen sometimes inserts calls to helper functions, the same way that gcc does for 64x64 multiply or divide on 32-bit platforms, or various other things.  (e.g. popcount on targets without hardware popcnt.)

In this case hand-holding MSVC into less-stupid code-gen (a good thing in itself) happens to remove all the uses of helper functions for your codebase.  That's good but doesn't fix your build setup.  **It can break again if you add code in the future that needs a helper**.  `uint64_t shr(uint64_t a, unsigned c) { return a >> c; }`  does compile to include a call to the helper function even at `-O2`.

A shift by a constant without optimization uses `_aullshr`, instead of inlining as `shrd` / `shr`.  **This exact problem (broken `-Od` builds) would recur with `uint64_t x` ; `x >> 4` or something in your source.**

(I don't know where MSVC keeps its library of helper functions.  We think it's a static library that you could link without introducing a DLL dependency (impossible for UEFI), but we don't know if its maybe bundled with some CRT startup code that you need to avoid linking with for UEFI.)

---

The un-optimized vs. optimized issue is clear with this example.  MSVC with optimization doesn't need the helper function, but its braindead `-Od` code *does*.

**For bitfield access, MSVC apparently uses a right shift of the base type of the bitfield member**.  In your case, you made it a 64-bit type, and 32-bit x86 doesn't have a 64-bit integer shift (except using MMX or SSE2).  With `-Od` even for constant counts it puts the data in EDX:EAX, the shift count in `cl` (just like for x86 shift instructions), and calls `__aullshr`.

- `__a` = ??
- `ull` = unsigned long long.
- `shr` = shift right (like the x86 asm instruction of the same name).
- it takes the shift count in `cl`, exactly like x86 shift instructions.

[From the Godbolt compiler explorer, x86 MSVC 19.16 `-Od`](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAOgCYAOAJyCALAFYADPwDswucNIArLqVbNaoZAFJeAIR27SAZ1QBXYsg4ByAgE8ADpixUA1KdpG8wWk5es6wH4BLgCqAJIAcgAqAGwiWgDM%2BhIAglqpdo7ObrR4dC5a0skpLqUuRgTEpsgEBUXpJWWZTpiu7p7evv4aQT0ARlQA%2BgSJxWUuAPQTzdntXj7oLgPDow3j48u1VHiYrOicLiAunDGrqetlmy7bu%2Bi8h8enSWsXS0NbO3sJD09jr1c3PYiB6cMRnRoXAGfdBiB68cGvN7Da7QmIghH/d4o27SdHPc6Y5GA9D8PG6UpTRIAYUSABE6QyEvSmYzmWyXpCscTBGSOesobdOBJeQTOUToZwDkdOBixR9BfdpaNJhNqaz1SzNeyWaL%2BVyJd8lfiIXrxYLgUa/qVCrSXLpCEZZTkOgteoFuoFacwCMxwTaXGEGAwQthBgwogAlEJUqJ%2B1J4egNACymAICAwnAgoUisWBry9PpcAEoGoUrQGgyGw5Ho1FERcwkYjKZMAxKtURsbxo3m632zVuAXmAUmS4h3GTXhXBAey221UB/aCEZuMTSazjgVeKdtwGm3P%2BwRuEuV8TOPcN5wi3VyVMRzStRuABLYCPYPnjYip8y0Y5Om18rsRiYHyZYfmUX4ED%2BLgSP%2B0j0qkAGIYhvAJAmyCsKYWD3hU%2BD0NwCCJO%2BqSmAmBBxMiRgIMQECkfQFG1MwpDOvMvjINeZYuJB0HDkRREuNoSR1LSVhFqoIBWGIVikLQEkSNJqASTSegGOUZgWJgW4JJw0kEHJoliQA1iACQJNw/ASAkEgxBIggSNI/AxJwsjiVYIjSQAtlwEgSDJ%2BmkIpVjSUYIC%2BXpVjyWJcCwEgaAefYeDsGQFAQHFCVJSAABuyD2PYgyZZwgiDCcgwAB6OaQ2ysAQmDECFEB9P5fQJswxC2BJOmkHFHmYPQADytCsO1EXSVgHnqMA7D%2BfgX41HgmWYCFI2kJgpWYMgpg1R10lkbs/msHgfTEK1thUhg1idZUeBeVYOliTQ9BMGwHA8AIwjiFIsjyAoagaCgBgGKoh0hbAtDMD1IB9KgqAVKQC3EB1MTSAZAX2AQeQeBJAC0fXoMF6mWFwYmsBJUl%2BctgXlWiHlGNlLgFYI3AnC4EC4IQJBaZwzFnfFiW1Zz17Kfoei6fpRZGSZYh8BIAhiLwghCjEMQJErYiue55PyQFEnBaFpDhZFpDRVAMCICgqC80l5CUGlfMI9luX5YVxUxGVFVVTVdWUI1y3NWDbXbV1Fs9f1g3DVrY0TVNy0zet6MLUtWuretm0XTt9B7ctB1HSdZ1YIHV03XdlV0IwLBTa9QiiJIMjfT9E3/SpehA30INQGDENQzDBBw7ViPI%2BLqPo3QS047w%2BPmITV6uWTskUxJVMuDTdMM0zaKs/gRDEJz3MW%2Bl/M6AkvCCwDIv62LEtWdw71SE5/CcCI0jiGrJNuZ5IBiFL2m8JwKsSCISMRDOREJrBSOtjB6wNqJI2psICxT3nba2qUEEZQwhNaQPlKqJU9vVH2Ws/YnUDt1XqBABpDWmpgcaGho4RzwLNeOi1/LJw2ltW66caqvy1tnY6bU85p31sQa6217qlyehXPgVcPq1zrqoBu2gm6GGzm3CAHcOBd1hvDfuKNUBowxqPPq3wsYeSPhPDSRMZ7STnlrSmjksZxAEr9QI0huASBcSzNmW8d4uB5vvbeh8EgnwUaLEag8ECYGYFgBGEBiYSQ1l5EQIhuAxBkI5BIggxBHzEPwbcoDtZBQgWFC%2BpBjJXxvo5Tg99H7P1cgkSx/lArBMijEqw49ckNPPiEsS8NPB0BACIIAA%3D), with `UINT64` as the bitfield member type.

```
;; from int Method1(unsigned __int64) PROC 
    ...
   ; extract IssueStruct.Bits.field8
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR _IssueStruct$[ebp]
    mov     edx, DWORD PTR _IssueStruct$[ebp+4]
    mov     cl, 57                                    ; 00000039H
    call    __aullshr        ; emulation of   shr  edx:eax,  cl
    and     eax, 1
    and     edx, 0
    ;; then store that to memory and cmp/jcc both halves.  Ultra braindead
```

**Obviously for constant shift and access to only 1 bit, that's easy to optimize, so MSVC doesn't actually call the helper function at `-O2`**.  It's still pretty inefficient, though!  It fails to fully optimize away the 64-bitness of the base type, even though none of the bitfields are wider than 32.

```
; x86 MSVC 19.16 -O2   with unsigned long long as the bitfield type
int Method1(unsigned __int64) PROC                              ; Method1, COMDAT
    mov     edx, DWORD PTR _Data$[esp]       ; load the high half of the inputs arg
    xor     eax, eax                         ; zero the low half?!?
    mov     ecx, edx                         ; copy the high half
    and     ecx, 33554432       ; 02000000H  ; isolate bit 57
    or      eax, ecx                         ; set flags from low |= high
    je      SHORT $LN2@Method1
    and     edx, 536870912      ; 20000000H   ; isolate bit 61
    xor     eax, eax                          ; re-materialize low=0 ?!?
    or      eax, edx                          ; set flags from low |= high
    je      SHORT $LN2@Method1
    mov     eax, 1
    ret     0
$LN2@Method1:
    xor     eax, eax
    ret     0
int Method1(unsigned __int64) ENDP                              ; Method1
```

Obviously this is really stupid materializing a `0` for the low half instead of just ignoring it.  **MSVC does much better if we change the bitfield member type to `unsigned`**.  (In the Godbolt link, I changed that to `bf_t` so I could use a typedef separate from UINT64, keeping that for the other union member.)

---

**With a struct based on `unsigned field : 1` bitfield members, MSVC doesn't need the helper at `-Od`**

**And it even makes better code at `-O2`,** so you should definitely do that in your real production code.  **Only use `uint64_t` or `unsigned long long` members for fields that need to be wider than 32 bits,** if you care about performance on MSVC which apparently has a missed-optimization bug with 64-bit types for bitfield members.

```
;; MSVC -O2 with plain  unsigned  (or uint32_t) bitfield members
int Method1(unsigned __int64) PROC                              ; Method1, COMDAT
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR _Data$[esp]
    test    eax, 33554432                     ; 02000000H
    je      SHORT $LN2@Method1
    test    eax, 536870912                    ; 20000000H
    je      SHORT $LN2@Method1
    mov     eax, 1
    ret     0
$LN2@Method1:
    xor     eax, eax
    ret     0
int Method1(unsigned __int64) ENDP                              ; Method1
```

---

I might have implemented it branchlessly like `((high >> 25) & (high >> 29)) & 1` with 2 `shr` instructions and 2 `and` instructions (and a `mov`).  If it's really predictable, though, branching is reasonable and breaks the data dependency.  clang does a nice job here, though, using `not` + `test` to test both bits at once.  (And `setcc` to get the result as an integer again).  This has better latency than my idea, especially on CPUs without mov-elimination.  clang doesn't have a missed optimization for bitfields based on 64-bit types, either.  We get the same code either way.

```
# clang7.0 -O3 -m32    regardless of bitfield member type
Method1(unsigned long long):                            # @Method1(unsigned long long)
    mov     ecx, dword ptr [esp + 8]
    xor     eax, eax           # prepare for setcc
    not     ecx
    test    ecx, 570425344     # 0x22000000
    sete    al
    ret
```

---

#### UEFI coding standard:

[The EDK II coding standard 5.6.3.4 Bit Fields](https://edk2-docs.gitbooks.io/edk-ii-c-coding-standards-specification/content/5_source_files/56_declarations_and_types.html#5634-bit-fields) says that:

- Bit fields may only be of type `INT32`, signed `INT32`, `UINT32`, or a typedef name defined as one of the three `INT32` variants.

I don't know why they make up these "INT32" names when C99 already has perfectly good `int32_t`.  It's also unclear why they'd place this restriction.  Perhaps because of the MSVC missed-optimization bug?  Or maybe to aid human programmer comprehension by disallowing some "weird stuff".

gcc and clang don't warn about `unsigned long long` as a bitfield type, even in 32-bit mode and with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`, in C or C++ mode.  I don't think ISO C or ISO C++ have a problem with it.

Further, [Should use of bit-fields of type int be discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940635/should-use-of-bit-fields-of-type-int-be-discouraged) points out that plain `int` as a bitfield type should be discouraged because the signedness is implementation-defined.  And that the ISO C++ standard discusses bitfield types from `char` to `long long`.

I think your MSVC warning about non-`int` bitfields must be from some kind of coding-standard-enforcement package, because normal MSVC on Godbolt doesn't do that even with `-Wall.

> warning C4214: nonstandard extension used: bit field types other than int

Comment: Indeed, when I compile the test.c with `/Od`, the MSVC compiler gives me this `warning C4214: nonstandard extension used: bit field types other than int`. Once I changed the bit field type from `UINT64` to `UINT32`, both the compiler warning C4214 and link error are gone.

Comment: @smwikipedia: your compiler is probably still broken, though.  `uint64_t shr(uint64_t a, unsigned c) { return a >> c; }` should still use the helper function.

Comment: I tried your `shr` sample, it can reproduce the same issue. And I tried on **another machine** which I used for long. The issue can be reproduced for both VC++2013 and VC++2015. So I guess my compiler installation is fine. The version I used are `C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.40629 for x86`, `C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24210 for x86`, and `C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24215.1 for x86`.

Comment: This code is part of the firmware. It **must not** link to any C runtime library. Maybe it's caused by some compiler option... Otherwise, it seems like a compiler issue. I will have to modify the code to use UINT32 to work around it.

Comment: @smwikipedia: In a normal program, is `__aullshr` in a DLL, or is it statically linked?  GCC also emits calls to helper functions for stuff like double-register-width multiply, but it statically links any required functions into the binary directly, by linking with `libgcc.a`.  To make a firmware binary with GCC, I think `-ffreestanding` would still link `libgcc.a` but like shared libraries like `libc.so` or `libc.dll`.

Comment: In my reproduce example, the unresolved `_aullshr` error happens during the linking phase of a DLL generation. So it must be *statically* linked. In my UEFI code scenario, it is also static linking. And the linked libs are strictly controlled, which doesn't involve any VC++ runtime libs.

Comment: @smwikipedia: Ok, so tell it to link with the library that provides the helper functions.  Or does MSVC only provide it in the same library as the full CRT startup code which you need to avoid for a UEFI application, instead of a Windows application?  At worst you might have to assemble the `.asm` that MS provides and link just the `.obj` files for the helpers your program ends up needing.

Comment: For now you don't actually need any, especially if you compile with optimization.  (You asked if it's a good idea to disable optimization for firmware.  No, why would you want slow bloated firmware?)

Comment: To fix this issue, I prefer to avoid using UINT64 as the base type for the bit field as you said. This also seems to be a bad practice. I need `/Od` because  `/O1` will lead to mismatch of source code lines during debug.

Comment: @smwikipedia: In your question, you asked if disabling optimization was a *good* practice.  It's not in general, only when you want it for debugging.   Maybe you meant to ask if there were any problems or reasons why disabling optimization was a *bad* practice that should always be avoided.  (It's not a bad practice for debugging, but it generally is for release.)

Comment: Anyway, like I said in my last comment, changing your source to work around MSVC anti-optimizations avoids the need for any helper functions for now.  But if at some point in the future you ever shift a 64-bit integer in your code, you're going to need the helper function again, at least in debug mode.

Comment: Yes, your word is more precise. For the 64-bit shift, I will have to use the substitute functions provided by UEFI: https://uefi.blogspot.com/2010/02/why-why-do-i-get-unresolved-externals.html. But in this bit filed case, I don't find such substitutes.

Comment: @PeterCordes +1 excellent response. The only thing I would add is to have a look at Section 5.6.3.4 of EDK II C Coding standard which specifically mentions Bit Fields. https://edk2-docs.gitbooks.io/edk-ii-c-coding-standards-specification/content/5_source_files/56_declarations_and_types.html#5634-bit-fields

Comment: @Stephano: Thanks, updated.  Why would they allow plain `INT32`, though, when that has implementation-defined signedness?  (Leading to possible breakage with compilers other than the one you test with.)  IMO a good coding standard would require the source to be explicit, like Keith Thompson says in [Should use of bit-fields of type int be discouraged?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25940635).  I also don't see any obvious reason why restricting the base type to `[u]int32` is necessary.

Comment: @PeterCordes That's a great question (aka I have no idea). You could bring it up at our community meeting next month :)  https://www.tianocore.org/community-meetings

Comment: @Stephano: I don't do UEFI development, so I don't plan on joining in that meeting just for this point.  I only saw this Q&A because of the intrinsics tag.  Feel free to use / cite anything I wrote if you want to bring it up yourself.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah, okay, understood. Thanks, I'll use your answer as a springboard for some conversation. Cheers!

Comment: @Stephano: I guess I'd add to my previous comment: if there's no easy way with MSVC to link its helper functions into an EFI application (that sounds crazy, what about explicit `int64_t` multiply or shift?) then restricting the base type to `[u]int32_t` is a useful workaround.  It's also a good idea for performance on MSVC, because of its missed optimizations with 64-bit base types.  And using a base type narrower than `int` doesn't have any obvious justification that I can see.  So maybe only use base types wider than 32 bits for fields wider than 32 bits?

Answer (score 1):

What you describe seems to be one of the following:

- a compiler bug only triggered with `/Od`. It would be very helpful if you can extract the structure definitions and the offending code in a minimal program that exhibits the problem for experts to investigate the problem.
- a compiler installation problem: you may be linking to a C library incompatible with your C compiler. This may cause further problems in other areas of your program. I would strongly advise you reinstall the compiler from scratch.

Comment: This is a clean installation of VS2015. My machine has only 1 instance of VS2015.